# building libzippp in macos with vcpkg: ld: library not found for -llibzip::libzip

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-code, vcpkg, libzip

[libzippp](https://github.com/ctabin/libzippp) github link

[vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) github link

It is supposed to be straightforward, according to the documentation one should "just" `./vcpkg install libzippp`

But i've tried it plus a little bit of everything but nothing works.

I'm using VS Code, my **CMakeLists.txt** is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(startProject)
set(Leptonica_DIR /Users/alejandrocamba/Documents/leptonica/build)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Leptonica REQUIRED)
find_package(Tesseract REQUIRED)
find_package(libzippp CONFIG REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Leptonica_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Tesseract_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(startProject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(startProject ${LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(startProject ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(startProject ${Tesseract_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(startProject PRIVATE libzip::libzip libzippp::libzippp)
```

I have `startProject PRIVATE libzip::libzip libzippp::libzippp` because vcpkg indicates that those are the targets for libzippp library.

On my c_cpp_properties.json i followed the documentation and included `"${vcpkgRoot}/x64-osx/include"`

```
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "${vcpkgRoot}/x64-osx/include",
            "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.3.0_5/include/opencv4",
            "/Users/Documents/leptonica/build/",
            "/Users/Documents/tesseract/build/"
        ]
```

And in settings.json:

```
  "cmake.configureSettings": {
    "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "${vcpkgRoot}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
  }
```

But i keep getting the same error, i'm not even specifying `libzip` as a target, only `libzippp`, so i'm guessing there's something going on with an internal dependency? where is libzippp looking for libzip??

I'm new to C++ and CMake! easy to understand examples/explanations are appreciated :)

You can assume i've tried a lot of SO question solutions and tutorials to try and solve this, asking this question is my final resource

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify both (remove `libzip::libzip`). Then, did you try deleting your CMakeCache.txt and re-running CMake from *scratch*?

Comment: Yes and yes! Leaving libzippp::libzippp behaves the same way and throws the same error, and i did delete cache and re-ran but error remains @squareskittles